# Adding by block in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829621/setting-variables-with-blocks-in-ruby) to this not too long ago in regards to formatting a MySQL query using a block and got very good responses, but they were very specific to the problem at hand. This time around, I'm dealing with getting the `.sum()`s of rows in a table. Here's what I've got now:

```
def balance
  balance = 0
  items.each do |item|
    balance = balance + item.charges.sum(:revenue, :conditions => ['created_at >= ?', Time.now.beginning_of_month])
  end
  balance
end
```

My goal here is to get the total of all charges for this month for a given user. Charges belong to items, which belong users. I'm sure there's a better way to do this in Ruby/Rails.

What would you do?

Comment: I'm not sure why several people here seem to be jumping on the approach of iterating over results, which is expensive, when you can do the entire calculation in SQL using the methods ActiveRecord provides. No .each, .map, .reduce, or .inject is necessary here.

Comment: Please see my comment after yours on my answer. I've tested this it, it works. This is exactly the sort of situation that SQL joins are for and there's no reason to iterate over your results, or do multiple queries (which Ian's second bit of code does), both of which add needless complexity and processing to your project.

Comment: @Jordan: I agree. Myself, I got too hung up on the specific *question* the OP was asking (how to sum numbers in a block), rather than looking at the actual *problem* at hand (summing values from a SQL table).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A straight conversion can be done:

```
def balance
  conds = ["created_at > ?", Time.now.beginning_of_month]
  items.inject(0) do |total, item|
    total + item.charges.sum(:revenue, :conditions => conds)
  end
end
```

There might be more optimal approaches depending upon how your relationships are mapped out.  For instance, you may be able to do something like:

```
def balance
  Charge.sum :revenue,
    :conditions => ["charges.item_id IN (?) AND created_at > ?",
      items.map { |item| item.id },
      Time.now.beginning_of_month]
end
```

For these kinds of situations, `map`, `inject`, `select`, and so forth, are invaluable tools.  [Here's a lengthy discussion on inject](http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/03/ruby-inject.html), and definitely consult the [RDoc's for the Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html) module for more information.

Comment: Might be more clear if you renamed the variable `acc` in your first example to `sum`.

Comment: Also, could store `Time.now.beginning_of_month` in a variable outside the `inject` block so it doesn't get recalculated in each iteration.

Comment: @Sarah, `sum` probably would be clearer, `acc` is just the variable name I instinctively go for when using `inject`, and nice catch on the `Time.now.beginning_of_month` re-evaluation.  It does add unnecessary cost, and in very rare circumstances could result in the wrong sum being calculated.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason not to do this in the SQL query itself, e.g:

```
Charges.sum :revenue, :conditions => [ "created_at >= ?, items.user_id = ?",
                                        Time.now.beginning_of_month, some_user_id ],
                      :joins => :items
```

**Edit:** It's unclear from the docs whether `sum` will take a symbol for :joins like `find` does. If it doesn't, your :joins line should look like this instead:

```
:joins => "JOIN items ON charges.item_id = items.id"
```

Comment: Jordan, unfortunately the user_id is not stored in the charges table, just the items table.

Comment: Bloudermilk: That's what the JOIN is for (I initially made it more complicated than it needed to be; I've fixed it). If charges belongs_to items and items belongs_to users you can do a JOIN with the items table to match against user_id. That's the whole point of joins, and you can do the entire calculation in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of general comments:

- I would suggest putting your code in the model rather than a controller, view, or helper, following the [Skinny Controller, Fat Model](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model) idea.
- Instead of writing `balance = balance + item.charges.sum(:revenue, :conditions => ['created_at >= ?', Time.now.beginning_of_month])` you can use `+=` and do:  `balance += item.charges.sum(:revenue, :conditions => ['created_at >= ?', Time.now.beginning_of_month])`.
- It's not technically a problem, but it seems bad form to have a variable the same name as your method (i.e., 'balance').
- I would store `Time.now.beginning_of_month` in a variable outside your loop so it doesn't get recalculated every time.

Comment: Thanks Sarah, that method is from the model. I didn't know Ruby supported +=! Good idea about storing Time.now.beginning_of_month outside the loop

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common recursion pattern. It is called a *catamorphsim* in category theory, a *fold* in mathematics and functional programming, it is also sometimes called *reduce* and in Smalltalk it is called `inject:into:`. In Ruby, it is called `inject` or `reduce` (these two methods are aliases).

The idea is that you have a collection of values and you want to "reduce" or "fold" that collection of multiple values into a single value. (The Smalltalk name `inject:into:` comes from the fact that you inject a starting value into a block which is called for each element of the collection.)

```
def balance
  this_month = Time.now.beginning_of_month
  items.reduce(0) { |balance, item|
    balance + item.charges.sum(:revenue, :conditions => ['created_at >= ?', this_month])
  }
end
```

Comment: Might follow Ruby convention of using `do` and `end` for a block you have on multiple lines.

Comment: There's two camps on this: one camp uses `do` / `end` for multiline and `{` / `}` for single line. The other uses `do` / `end` for imperative and `{` / `}` for functional style blocks. I belong to the latter camp.